# Parse PFLogin email verification

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, email-validation, login-control

I wonder if anyone is able to provide a code example of Parse login where the email address must be validated and also must be from a specific address. I believe it is something like;
[query whereKey:@"emailVerified" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
and 
[query whereKey:@"comment" containsString:@"@gmail.com"];
but I have been unable to get this working in my project.
Any help or suggestions would be great but a piece of code would be awesome

Below is my existing code which will not let an unverified email user login but now I want to add the email handle

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {

    if (![[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]){
        NSLog(@"User not validated email");
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access restricted" message:@"To access this area please validate your email address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    else if ([[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]){
        NSLog(@"Email validated");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome back" message:(@"%@", user.username) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSLog(@"Login sucessfull and username is %@",user.username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing this check prior to allowing the user to login? If so the email being verified can be checked easily.

You can create a helper method with the following

```
- (void)methodname:(PFUser *)User {

    if (![[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]) {
            // make sure user did not recently verify email address
        [user refresh];

        if (![[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]) {
            // handle how you want to tell user they need to verify email address
            [self redirectWithMessage:@"You must verify your email address"];
            return;
        }

 } else if {

          // check for specific address and handle if doesn't meet that requirement

}  else {

    // The user verified and email is of correct address - send user to view

}
```

Working from cell phone, please excuse it not being in a full code block.

Comment: This helped and if you have a look at the code I have now added you may be able to help some more. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide details on your email requirements?

Comment: I would only like one email handle to be able to login to a certain area. It contains some info that I don't want sharing with a wider audience. the email then has be verified so you know they work there. The email will be something like john.smith@fire.gov.uk. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I think the best way would be to setup would be using roles through the parse framework which can be seen through here https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#roles/iOS . You should be able to create roles specific to your needs using the above link. Admins can access ABC whereas Regular user can access XYZ.  Once you have created the roles and assigned the user their roles you can perform a query of the current user and determine their role. You can perform this check after the user login is successful prior to any navigation.  Use if / else if statements based on role to perform navigation.

Comment: Hi jimrice, i posted above the code I used to get it working but did not use Parse roles or ACL. Thanks for the assistance though.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions and comments. I managed to solve it, for some reason could not work it out yesterday. The i believe answer is;

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {

if (![[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]){

    NSLog(@"User refresh");

    // make sure user did not recently verify email address

    [user refresh];

if (![[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue])
    NSLog(@"User not validated email");
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access restricted" message:@"To access this area please validate your email address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}



    if (![[user objectForKey:@"email"] containsString:@"gmail.com"]) {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You must have a validated gmail.com email to access this area." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

        NSLog(@"Email not verified or not a gmail email");
}
else if ([[user objectForKey:@"emailVerified"] boolValue]){
    NSLog(@"Email validated");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome back" message:(@"%@", user.username) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
// [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (user.objectForKey("emailVerified").boolValue == true){
                    println("true")
                } else {
                    println("false")
                }
```

Comment: Firstly, this is swift. Secondly, please add some form of explanation to your code snippet.